# What is the equivalent of Windows System Properties or Device Manager?

Tags: drivers, software-recommendation, command-line, windows, hardware

I am new to Ubuntu. In Windows, if I want to know my system properties/configuration, I can see it by going to Control Panel and clicking on the System icon. I can also get a detailed list of the hardware detected/installed by going to the Device Manager.

What are the equivalents of these features in Ubuntu, where a user can see his or her system properties and hardware configuration, like RAM, CPU/processor, hard disk capacity, etc.?

---

**Example of Windows System Properties:**

[image]

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### For Basic Information

Go to Settings, and under System, click on Details for basic information:

[image]

### For Detailed Information (like Windows Device Manager)

- Search for "system" in Software Center, and install *System Profiler and Benchmark*:

  [image]
- Then run it from the Launcher (type "system" if it isn't there already), and you will see a detailed list of hardware that you can expand further by category:

[image]

- This tool also allows you to run benchmarks to compare how your system performs relative to other common computers.
- Scroll down for examples of CPU and RAM information.

---

### Other system-specific tools and console (terminal) tools

Please see Luis Alvarado's [excellent exhaustive answer with screenshots](https://askubuntu.com/a/146638/58612)  to this question, just above or below this one.

---

#### Examples of CPU and RAM information as shown in System Profiler

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the package name? I didn't catch it anywhere in the post.

Comment: This is a great answer, but unfortunately that tool doesn't seem to let you disable a driver or even see its related module (a la lsmod).

Answer (score 33):

Open the terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type any of these:

For cpu info

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

For memory info

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

to see disk usage of various partitions

```
df -h
```

See ram usage

```
free -m
```

wireless network

```
iwconfig
```

Which ubuntu is running in your computer

```
lsb_release -a
```

Find your kernel info

```
uname -a
```

list all hardware

```
sudo lshw
```

All soundcards

```
aplay -l
```

Some graphical software for the same will be

### 1)Hardware lister

[image]

Whenever you want to run it type `sudo lshw-gtk` in the terminal

#### Download it here

[image]

### 2)Sysinfo

[image]

[image]

### 3)System Profiler and Benchmark

[image]

[image]

Comment: @izx He is attempting to make the accepted answer the best answer he can make it. I'd say that is a valid answer.

Comment: @jrg Fair enough, I hadn't looked at it from that perspective and agree wholeheartedly.  However he should attribute the screenshots not just as a courtesy, but also because a newbie may be confused because each is of a different system.

Answer (score 20):

Without going into terminal commands (From my point of view, less friendly way of inviting a new user to Ubuntu.. until he/she feels the force) like:

`lshw` - Shows you information about all hardware
`lsusb` - Shows you information about all USB hardware
`lspci` - Shows information about all PCI compatible hardware
`cat /proc/cpuinfo` - Shows detailed information about your CPU
`dmidecode` - Shows you information about hardware

And others like `lm-sensors` or `hdparm` that can give information about HDD and temperature readings.

Seeing as you are new, I will mention easy to use GUI tools that can quickly help you find important information about your PC:

## DISK UTILITY

Shows information about all type of storage devices, including but not limited to HDD, SDD, Flash Drives, External (Connected) USB Drives, etc..

[image]

To use it just open DASH (By pressing the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key) and type `disk`. You will then see the option "Disk Utility".

[image]

## DISK USAGE ANALYZER

Very good program to analyze the (As the obvious name implies) disk usage. It can very useful when doing a cleanup on old files and such.

[image]

As with Disk Utility, type in dash `disk` and the second option will be the "Disk Usage Analyzer"

## Ubuntu Detail Information

Type in dash `detail` and you will see a cog icon with the name "Details". It will show you basic information on your machine:

[image]

[image]

I should mention that if you are using an Nvidia card, you need to update Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest upgrades in order to see the Video card name.

## SYSINFO

Very nice program to see information about your computer.

[image]

It can be installed via the Software Center by looking for "Sysinfo" or "Hardware"
or clicking [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sysinfo) [image: Install sysinfo]

[image]

## HARDWARE LISTER

Very nice program based on LSHW to show you in a graphical way all the hardware. As the previous one I mentioned, it can also be installed from the Software Center by looking for "Hardware" or clicking [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sysinfo) [image: Install sysinfo]

[image]

[image]

So as you can see there are MANY programs to check for hardware and hardware information in general. I suggest playing with Software Center to find even more but this should be enough to know most if not everything about your computer.

Comment: Fantastic job, Luis! I was not aware of some of the GUI tools you described myself - and I'm lazy so I just linked the last part of my answer to yours ;)

Comment: hehe oki. No problem.

Answer (score 10):

Try using hardinfo (System information and benchmarking tool)

Install via the terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

Or use the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Invoke with the Dash and click on the summary tab[image: hardinfo]

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

Then launch it!