# What is the Ubuntu equivalent of the Windows programs Belarc or PC Wizard?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent of Windows System Properties or Device Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146621/what-is-the-equivalent-of-windows-system-properties-or-device-manager)

I provide technical support for several high schools in Spain and I have been building up a inventory of the schools machines. On the windows only computers I normally run PC Wizard to quickly get a good overview of the machines hardware, software and network settings. Is there an equivalent tool preferable with a GUI and an export option to html or pdf in Ubuntu.

I have tried a few options such as:
Gnomes gconf-editor
hardinfo (GUI)
lshw (CLI)

I'm just looking for an all in one application that builds a detailed profile of the installed software, hardware and network setting of a particular machine.

*I have found Sysinfo which is quite good, it displays the most important hardware info and allows you to save it to a text file with a neat GUI. I'm still looking for a more complete solution but it's a good start.*

Comment: Similar Question [What is the equivalent of Windows System Properties in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/146621/what-is-the-equivalent-of-windows-system-properties-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the link mentioned by izx and tried all the options suggested and the one that meets the needs of the question is **System Profiler and Benchmark**

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hardinfo/

It gives a huge amount of information for easily adding equipment to an inventory and more importantly it has the option to save it in HTML format.

[image: System Profiler and Benchmark]

I think that this is a legitimately different question that will help people looking for Ubuntu equivalents of two very popular Windows inventory applications Belarc and PC Wizard.

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer; I agree it's a different question and is helpful. Please remember to accept your own answer (you must wait at least 2 days after posting the question)